# Appropriate way to pass instance of class to other classes (Java)

Tags: java, instance

I have a main class which has a number of instance related methods that are often needed in other classes and I often find myself passing an instance of the main class in the constructor. I often find this goes several layers deep with classes having instances of the main class that has been copied from instance to instance which I can't imagine is good for memory usage.

Is there a way to do this without having to pass the instance in the constructor or a method or at least a way to reduce the memory that is used by the instances of the main class.

To make it clear I am not looking for static methods, it is designed to be able to have more than one instance of the main class.

Example code:

```
public class Main {
    public Main() {
        Class2 class2 = new Class2(this);
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        //Do something
    }
}

public class Class2 {
    private final Main instance;

    public Class2(Main instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
        Class3 class3 = new Class3(instance);
    }
}

public class Class3 {
    private final Main instance;

    public Class3(Main instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
        instance.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: you realize that the fields only use 32/64 bits of memory as they are merely references to your instance, right? So, you don't actually have a "memory problem" here.

Comment: Juice? Spring? Dependency Injection -- Decoupling is the key!! And if someone tells you to make a method static or do anything else to make your code non-OOP compliant, do yourself a favor and just ignore them.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Not that you're wrong in this particular example, but is that a universal truth? Is something wrong with static utility method(s)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: no, you are correct, utility methods **should** be static. But to use static as a broad answer when nothing was mentioned about these being utility methods is wrong.

Comment: The name of the class, "Main", strongly suggests that there is no need to have more than one instance of the class or copy of its data in the application.  If you don't need more than one instance, static methods or a singleton are the appropriate solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dependency Injection Design Pattern.

[Dependency-Injection-Design-Pattern](http://www.journaldev.com/2394/dependency-injection-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial)

> Spring, Google Guice and Java EE CDI frameworks facilitate the
>   process of dependency injection through use of Java Reflection API and
>   java annotations. All we need is to annotate the field, constructor or
>   setter method and configure them in configuration xml files or
>   classes.

Comment: I've found Spring dependency injection with configuration files to be a solution that's worse than the problem.  Typically the configuration files needed in deployment are different from the configuration files used in test, since the latter often use mocks or stubs to avoid having to test in a full deployment style environment.  The result is that the deployment configuration files are never tested, and cause problems in operation.

Comment: @WarrenDew I am not insisting the OP to go for Spring Framework only for this.OP can choose as per the requirement.

Comment: Your quote implies the use of configuration files, which will run into the problems I mentioned.  I would grant that use of, say, Guice with configuration in the code rather than in separate configuration files might not run into this problem, but it might also be harder to test - and your answer doesn't mention the alternative of configuration in the code, anyway.

Comment: @WarrenDew you can use annotations in Spring to Configure in code instead of xml file.

Comment: @WarrenDew Please read this ' configure them in configuration xml files or classes.' which is there in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could also use dependency injection to pass on the dependent attributes or objects to required classes.
One such popular framework is [Google Guice.](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/)

Answer (score -2):

You could make methods like someMethod() in the Main class static, or if that's not possible, make the Main class itself a singleton.

Example of the former approach:

```
public class Main {
    public Main() {
        Class2 class2 = new Class2(this);
    }

    public static void someMethod() {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Now you don't have to pass an instance of Main around any more, because other classes can just call `Main.someMethod()` directly.

Comment: Hm, downvotes with no reasons.  I guess there are people out there who don't actually write code that has to be deployed and work.

Comment: From my understanding if I made a method in the main class static then it wouldn't be able to return the instance as the method belongs to the class instead of the object.

Comment: There is no indication in the question that a static method is a valid solution to the problem (there may be multiple instances of the "main" class).  Furthermore, I find that careless application of static methods in non-utility classes tends to lead to brittle and difficult to test code.

Comment: @user2248702 You would make the methods in the Main class static, not the Main class itself.  I've added a code example to clarify.

Comment: @Aurand There is no indication that a static method is not a valid solution, either.  That's why I provided two solutions:  one in for the case where static methods are appropriate, and one where they are not.  However, given the class is called "Main", I strongly suspect that unlike most classes, its data is likely to be globally applicable and thus that static functions are likely to be appropriate.  I've gotten into a lot more trouble trying overly hard to avoid static methods and data than from using them, although I'm not careless about either.